# Block User scroll when full screen menu is open

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, navigation

i'm working on a full screen menu for a website but I need to disable the user to scroll while the menu is open. I can't find a fitting solution on the internet so it would be great if anyone could help me. I am not sure how to trigger the body to no-scroll if the menu is open. I am not that familiar with js.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
<body id="body">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/Gautama_Buddha_pic.png">
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">ARTIST</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="">EXHIBITIONS</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="">EVENTS</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="">VISIT US</a></li>         
                </ul>
                <p class="lite-text">MENU</p>
                <img src="images/close-line.png" class="close-icon" onclick="closemenu()">
            </nav>
            <img src="images/hamburger-menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="openmenu()">
        </div>
    </div> 

    <section class="one">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="two"></section>
    <section class="three"></section>
    <section class="four"></section>
    <section class="five"></section>
    
<script>
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    function closemenu(){

        menu.style.top = "-100vh";
    }

    function openmenu(){

        menu.style.top = "0";
    }
</script>

</body>
```

And that's the CSS

```
        *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo img{
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 35px 0;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 35px 0;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
    background: #dfa24e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -100vh;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lite-text{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 200px;
    letter-spacing: 100px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-weight: 800;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px #000;
}

.close-icon{
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 80px;
    top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon{
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.one{
    background-color: tomato;
}
.two{
    background-color: thistle;
}
.three{
    background-color: blue;
}
.four{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.five{
    background-color: wheat;
}

    .no-scroll {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `document.querySelector('body').classList.add('no-scroll')` when menu opened & `document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('no-scroll')` when menu closed.

```css
        *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo img{
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 35px 0;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 35px 0;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
    background: #dfa24e;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}

nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -100vh;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lite-text{
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 200px;
    letter-spacing: 100px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-weight: 800;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 5px #000;
}

.close-icon{
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 80px;
    top: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon{
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.one{
    background-color: tomato;
}
.two{
    background-color: thistle;
}
.three{
    background-color: blue;
}
.four{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
.five{
    background-color: wheat;
}

    .no-scroll {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/Gautama_Buddha_pic.png">
            </div>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">ARTIST</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="">EXHIBITIONS</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="">EVENTS</a></li>         
                    <li><a href="">VISIT US</a></li>         
                </ul>
                <p class="lite-text">MENU</p>
                <img src="images/close-line.png" class="close-icon" onclick="closemenu()">
            </nav>
            <img src="images/hamburger-menu.png" class="menu-icon" onclick="openmenu()">
        </div>
    </div> 

    <section class="one">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </section>
    <section class="two"></section>
    <section class="three"></section>
    <section class="four"></section>
    <section class="five"></section>
    
<script>
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    function closemenu(){
                 
        document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('no-scroll')
        menu.style.top = "-100vh";
    }

    function openmenu(){
        document.querySelector('body').classList.add('no-scroll')
        menu.style.top = "0";
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You are amazing man! Tanks a lot.